Probablistic Assumption on Linear Regression
I am reading Stanford CS229's lecture notes online and on page 16 (page 17 in PDF page identification) and I am stuck on understanding a good portion of the page. For the context, we assume that the target variables $y^{(i)}$ and the inputs $x^{(i)}$ are related via the equation $y^{(i)} = \theta^T x^{(i)} + \epsilon^{(i)}$, with the error terms $\epsilon^{(i)}$ with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$. It then says the following:

... the density [function] of $\epsilon^{(i)}$ is given by


$$p(\epsilon^{(i)}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \exp (-\frac{(\epsilon^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2}).$$
This implies that, [for a fixed $\theta$,]
$$p(y^{(i)} | x^{(i)} ; \theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \exp (-\frac{(y^{(i)} - \theta^T x^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2}).$$

I don't get exactly why $p(y^{(i)} | x^{(i)} ; \theta) = p(\epsilon^{(i)}$. Also, down in the same page, there is the equation $L(\theta) = L(\theta; X, \vec{y}) = p(\vec{y} | X ; \theta)$. I get that $\theta$ is an unknown variable in the likelihood function, but what does $X$ and $\vec{y}$ stand for? I thought that, in a likelihood function, sample points are fixed, it's most sensible to say that $X$ is the design matrix and $\vec{y}$ is a column vector with $i$-th entry as $y^{(i)}$. Am I right in this? Also, I find the notation a little strange; to be very technical, according to the notation from wikipedia's likelihood page, $L(\theta; X, \vec{y}) = p(X, \vec{y}; \theta)$, or at least $L(\theta) = L(\theta; \vec{y} | X)$? Is there a reason for this?

The lecture notes clarify the notation:

To establish notation for future use, we’ll use $x^{(i)}$ to denote the “input” variables (living area in this example), also called input features, and y^{(i)} to denote the “output” or target variable that we are trying to predict (price). A pair $\left ( x^{(i)}, y^{(i)} \right )$ is called a training example, and the dataset that we’ll be using to learn—a list of n training examples $ \{ x^{(i)}, y^{(i)};i = 1,\dots,n \}$—is called a training set. Note that the superscript “$(i)$” in the notation is simply an index into the training set, and has nothing to do with exponentiation


Given a training set, define the design matrix $X$ to be the $n$-by-$d$ matrix (actually $n$-by-$d$ + 1, if we include the intercept term) that contains the training examples’ input values in its rows. Also, let $\vec{y}$ be the $n$-dimensional vector containing all the target values from
the training set:

In this context, we assume the input and target variables are related by the following equation:
$$ 
y^{(i)} = \theta^T x^{(i)} + \varepsilon^{(i)} 
\hspace{0.5em} \text{for} \hspace{0.5em} 
\varepsilon^{(i)} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^{2})
$$
In plain English, we are assuming that the data is adequately modelled by a linear relation plus some Gaussian Noise sampled from IID $ \varepsilon^{(i)} $.
Now, our task is to recover $ \theta $ from the training data.
We start by computing the probability of observing $ y^{(i)} $ given $ x^{(i)} $ parametrized by $ \theta $ by noting that $ \varepsilon^{(i)} = y^{(i)} - \theta^T x^{(i)} $.
$$
p(y^{(i)} \mid x^{(i)}; \theta) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} \exp \left( -\frac{(y^{(i)} - \theta^T x^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)
$$
With independence satisfied, we may express the probability of observing the labels given the data and parameters.
$$
p(y \mid X; \theta) = 
\prod_{i = 1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} \exp \left( -\frac{(y^{(i)} - \theta^T x^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)
$$
Our task is find the choice of parameters $ \theta $ which maximizes the likelihood of observing the labels. As typical, in maximum likelihood estimation, we will notice that taking the natural log preserves the $ \mathrm{argmax} $ and simplifies the relevant calculus.
$$
L(\theta) = 
\sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left [ \ln \left ( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} \right ) + \left( -\frac{(y^{(i)} - \theta^T x^{(i)})^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \right ]
$$
It is clear that the log-likelihood is maximized precisely when $ \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{(y^{(i)} - \theta^T x^{(i)})^2}{2} $ or the sum of square residuals is minimized.
Discussion online suggests that AI: A Modern Approach is a good introductory text for someone with a strong mathematical background.
